# Multiple columns in css with different inputs

Tags: html, css

Basically, I need to get two columns with two different inputs. But they'd need to be on the same row, and both responsive.

The first one would be:

The second is: 
How it looks:
[image: Looks]

How it should look:[image: need]

I assume I've made some silly error.

```
  <body>
<div id="menu1">
<div id="menu2">
<h1>
Treatments:
</h1>

<hr>


   <div class="treatments">
   <div class="options">
    <p> Item 1  </p>
    <p> Item 1  </p>
    <p> Item 1  </p>
    <p> Item 1  </p>
    <p> Item 1  </p>
    <p> Item 1  </p>
    <p> Item 1  </p>    
   <div class="prices">
   <p> $NAN </p>
    <p> $NAN    </p>
     <p> $NAN   </p>
      <p> $NAN  </p>
       <p> $NAN </p>
      <p> $NAN  </p>
         <p> $NAN         </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#menu1{
        position: relative;
        max-width: 814px;
        /*background:rgba(123,123,123,0.5);*/
        background:#ccc;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        border-radius:12px;
        /* shadow */
        box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
        /* shadow*/
        }


        div#menu1 
        div#menu2{
        position: relative;
        max-width: 727px;
        padding: 36px;
        border: 7px solid #000;
        border-radius:5px;
        }

        hr {
        border: none;
        height: 5px;
        background:#000000;
        /* width:50%;*/
        }

        .treatments{


         }

        .options{
        text-align:left; !important

        }


       .prices{
          text-align:right;!important
         }
```

Comment: Give semo-colon after !important ---- text-align:right !important;

Comment: try adding `display: inline-block` to `prices` and `options`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html should be in the first place understandable/readable without any style . name + price together :)

Example with a list

```css
ul {
  border:solid 10px;
  padding:0.25em;
  width:400px;
  line-height:1.6em;
  font-size:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:0.5em;
}
li {
  display:block;
  }
li em {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><em>Name:</em> Price:</li>
  <li><em>Name:</em> Price:</li>
  <li><em>Name:</em> Price:</li>
  <li><em>Name:</em> Price:</li>
  <li><em>Name:</em> Price:</li>
  <li><em>Name:</em> Price:</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: @erick you could copy paste your code in codepen or jsfiddle and use the tidy up option to retrieve a code .. tied up ;) http://codepen.io/pen

Comment: Off topic question, how do I make it float universally centered regardless of users screen size?
(I'll use code pen next time)

Comment: @EricERK if you mean <ul> , then use margin:auto; not float. Maybe you will find usefull the INFO section of the CSS tag here : http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

Comment: I mean how do I make the whole "shape" float from the X and Y axis basically at 0,0, if that makes sense?

UL is the id of the element, so it may be <ul>

Comment: @EricERK maybe this deserve a new clean question, if it's about centered x,y at screen , many methods can be used from display to position.